# TensorFlow: How to smoothly use pipeline to load, train and predict images?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm confused about the read data and the batch related things.

I read png like this:

```
trainInputQueue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filePaths, shuffle=False)
key, value = tf.WholeFileReader().read(trainInputQueue)
images = tf.image.decode_png(value, channels=0)
images = tf.reshape(images, para['shape'])
images.set_shape(para['shape'])
images = tf.cast(images, tf.float32) * (1. / 255) - 0.5
return images
```

Then the resulted trainX, testX are all read with the above code. They are all pngs.

Then I define my network with `tf.placeholder` as input and output.

Then I make batches with:

```
trainXBatch, trainYBatch = tf.train.batch(
    [trainX, trainY],
    batch_size=batch_size
)
```

Till here, they are all traditional things. The data read are tensor, not numpy.ndarray or lists.

Then my questions are below. And I really need some example codes to learn:

## 1. about training

```
val, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: trainXBatch.eval(), Y: trainYBatch.eval()})
```

When I train the model, how can I make sure I used all the data? 
What way the "eval()" works? each time it return new `batch_size` data or other way? 
I tried

```
for i in range( a very big number):
    val, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: trainXBatch.eval(), Y: trainYBatch.eval()})
```

The 'eval()' can always return data, and the datas are not same. I don't know whether I used all the data and whether the returned data from eval are valid.

The example in tensorflow with mnist have a function named "next_batch", but I don't have this thing when I use my own data...

I just want to know how to use the data to train with label in a traditional way like keras does.

## 2. about model saving

In training phase, I use saver as:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
with tf.Session() as sess:
    #...some codes
    saver.save(sess, model_path + '/' + modelNamePrefix + model_name)
```

and in prediction phase:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
# other codes same as training phase
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    saver.restore(sess, model_path + '/' + modelNamePrefix + model_name)
    # then use sess.run to predict
```

are these codes right? I didn't get well results so I'm not sure whether it works.

## 3. about prediction

The question is like question 1, about the eval.
For example I have 1000 images to predict, the images are in testX, and `print(testX.get_shape())` I can see (?, 32, 32, 3), the same as trainX.
But with the same model, testX.eval() cannot directly send to feed_dict.
perhaps I still need to

```
testXBatch, testYBatch = tf.train.batch(
    [testX.data, testY.data],
    batch_size=1
)
```

But! How can I make sure I predict all the test data?
I just use

```
for i in range(a big number):
    yimgs = sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict={X: testXBatch.eval()})
```

and the program can output "a big number" images more than the test images I have.
How can I predict the test images in a comfortable way?

Answer (score 0):

### Part 1

To your first question, according to [the `tf.train.batch` documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch), that object will throw a `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` when the batch is exhausted. It also contains an element `capacity` that tells you how many items are in the queue. You can make your `for` loop run until the queue is exhausted, and just in case look for that error:

```
try:
    for _ in range(a_batch.capacity // a_batch.batch_size):
        # run your training operation
except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    pass
```

### Part 2

As to your second question, I just spent some time dealing with saving and restoring as well. Check out [this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/meta_graph) for some explanation. Basically you save the model the way that you are, but I would recommend assigning a unique value to the `name` field of any operations or variables you are going to want to work with later. This makes it much easier to get those back later. When you save your model, you get a file called `[filename].meta`. To restore your session and graph:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()  # include this if you are working in a notebook and may already have a graph designed
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/path/to/[filename].meta')
sess = tf.Session()
saver.restore(sess, '/path/to/[filename]')  # leave off the ".meta"
graph = sess.graph
```

And to load any operations or variables that you named use:

```
tensor_name = graph.get_tensor_by_name('tensor_name:0')  # note the ":0"
```

If you saved off any operators with [`tf.add_to_collection()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add_to_collection), use:

```
op_name = tf.get_collection('op_name')[0]
```

### Part 3

Possibly trickier? How are you setting up your network's data placeholders? If you define them like:

```
data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 32, 32, 3], name='data')
```

then you should be able to feed any batch size to your network and it will magically crunch it:

```
test_error = sess.run(my_error_op, feed_dict={data: all_the_test_data})
```

I found [this example on GitHubGist](https://gist.github.com/danijar/61f9226f7ea498abce36187ddaf51ed5) to be helpful for understanding this. It doesn't sound like it is exactly like your problem, but may help you get to the bottom of this issue.